# Process Json request with Multipart File

Tags: rest, spring-boot, file, multipart

I am passing Multipart file with other user information . i am getting Failed to convert property value of type `java.lang.String` to required type `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile` for property `file;` nested exception is `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile'`

Below code I have tried

```
private String useremail;

private int employeecode;

private MultipartFile file;
```

controller class

@RequestMapping(value = RestMappingUrls.User.saveUser, headers = {"content-type=multipart/mixed","content-type=multipart/form-data"}  )
public RestResponse saveUser(@ModelAttribute UserPojo user) throws IllegalStateException, IOException
{

Answer (score 0):

you can try with the below approach

```
 @RequestMapping(value = RestMappingUrls.User.saveUser, method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
 public RestResponse saveUser(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestPart FormWrapper formWrapper) {
 }

 public class FormWrapper {
    private String useremail;
    private int employeecode;

}
```

Comment: what exception you are getting?